# Ganache-Cli and Metamask generates completely different accounts from the same mnemonic

Tags: ethereum, metamask, ganache

When I run

> ganache-cli -m impose royal miracle dismiss scale quiz sausage bus odor liar rent scheme country lend vivid demand autumn purpose clog skill symptom ketchup fringe hen

I get these accounts in the terminal

(0) 0x22c0D02Df846Df59955c991C0359acD414387Bb0 (100 ETH)

(1) 0x433Ff1a6D635E9F294916c8A83629A18539391CF (100 ETH)

Whereas if I use Metamask I get

(0) 0x588fcACd850599385705789156F0066c470bf9Da

(1) 0xDCd05B8eD4158F27BFd515C7e001a35EB40e8B2e

Why is there a discrepancy? Shouldn't they give the same address?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to import Ganache accounts into your Metamask?.